# chart.js function delay not affect my graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js, delay

I am asking you because I created a chart with chart.js and I would like to assign it a delay before it appears, after reading the docs and different forums I get the following code which unfortunately does not work. Thanking you in advance for your help!

```
var cts = document.getElementById('myDonutChart').getContext('2d');
var myDonutChart = new Chart(cts, {
     type: 'doughnut',
     data: {
           labels:[
                   //requete sql
                   'Red',
                   'Blue',
                   'Yellow'
                  ],
 
            datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
                            data: [
                            //requete sql
                            12,
                            19,
                            3,
                            5,
                            2,
                            3
                            ],
                            backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                        },
                        options: {
                        legend: { display: false },
                        responsive: false,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        animation: {
                           delay: 4000
                           }
                        }
                    });
```

Reading the doc gives me the result with the delay function or alone it doesn't work and the only solution I found was to add a setimout but I still wanted to find the solution to the delay problem

Comment: If you want to delay the display of the chart, then only `setTimeout` will do it for you. There is a `delay.animation` with chart, but it only delays the animation